# Extract strings in quotation marks and brackets

Tags: regex, preg-match-all, pcre

My string test is :

```
My name is "Ralph" ("France" is my country, "123" my age, ... , "an other text", ...)
```

I want to get strings in quotation marks, but only these in brackets. In my example : strings `France` and `123`.

I've tested this pattern :

```
#\(.*"(.*)".*\)#
```

but it only matches the last string `123` (I use `preg_match_all()`, so it should return every result, no?)

If I add the `U`ngreedy option it matches only the first string `France`. So I don't understand why it wasn't greedy without the U option, and is there a way to obtain my strings in quotation marks and in brackets?

Thanks,
Raphaël N.

Comment: it's winding me up that I can't get this to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get this to work is by using:

```
$subject = 'My 00123450 "Ralph" ("France" is my country, "123" my age, ... , "an other text", ...)';

$pattern =  '/\((?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?(?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?(?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?[^"]*?\)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($matches); $i++)
{
    print($i.': '.$matches[$i][0].";\n");
}
```

**Output:**

```
1: France; 
2: 123; 
3: an other text;
```

That Regex would only work for *up to* 3 occurrences of "quoted strings" inside a set of brackets. You could however extend the regex string to grab *up to* N occurrences as follows:

The regex to find 1 to N quoted strings within each set of parenthesis is:

```
n=1 /\((?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?[^"]*?\)/
n=2 /\((?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?(?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?[^"]*?\)/
n=3 /\((?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?(?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?(?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?[^"]*?\)/
```

To find 1-N strings you repeat the section `(?:[^"\)]*"(.*?)")?` N times. For 1-100 strings within each set of parenthesis you would have to repeat that section 100 times - obviously the regex would start evaluating very slowly.

I realise that isn't by any means ideal, but its my best effort at a 1 pass solution.

**In 2 passes:**

```
$subject = 'My name is "Ralph" ("France" is my country, "123" my age, ... , "an other text", ...)';

$pattern =  '/\(.*?\)/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

$pattern2 =  '/".*?"/';
preg_match_all($pattern2, $matches[0][0], $matches2);

print_r($matches2);
```

Produces correct output in 2 passes. Eagerly awaiting an answer that shows how to do it in 1 though. I've tried every variation I could think of, but can't get it to include overlapping matches.

Comment: Thanks for your trouble.

I thought it was a basic need provided by PCRE regex (useful for parsing BBCode or HTML maybe? I've to search in that direction).
But for my needs I'm going to use a 2 passes solution, waiting for a hypothetical 1 passe solution.

Comment: I thought it would be simple for sure.. had to post my full failed attempt up because I wasted so much time trying to crack it ;)

Comment: I wonder if assertions ([link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)) can help. My idea is to get all strings in quotation marks if there is no open bracket after. But at the moment I don't succeed in getting assertions working (I never use them before).
I'll keep you informed!

Comment: I tried all sorts of assertions to no avail. I think assertions might work if you were allowed variable length lookbehinds like (?<=.*), but you're not, so you can never include the characters between the ( and the " in the assertions. I just had the idea that maybe (?<=.{1,1000}) would be allowed, but its not :( yup keep me updated if you have any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and do it in 2 steps:

```
$s = 'My name is "Ralph" ("France" is my country, "123" my age) and "I" am. ';
$str = preg_replace('#^.*?\(([^)]*)\).*$#', '$1', $s);
if (preg_match_all('/"([^"]*)"/', $str, $arr))
   print_r($arr[0]);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "France"
    [1] => "123"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
\("([^"]+)".+?"(.+)"
```

Explained:

`\("` - match a bracket and double quote

`([^"]+)"` - capture everything inside double quotes

`.+?"` - match anything up to the next double quote

`(.+)` - capture everything that isn't a double quote

`"` - match last double quote

As long as your sample data is exactly as given, the regex should work

Comment: fails if the `(` isn't immediately followed by a `"`

Comment: @OGHaza yes it would. but that isn't in the sample data, nor said that it would occur. i can only work off what OP provides.

Comment: true but then (123|France) is a totally valid answer

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I forget to say that the number of text in quotation marks to be captured isn't fixed. It's my fault.
At the same time, there is only one pair of bracket.